# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError powermock

Tags: java, junit, easymock, powermock, jmock

Guys
Question:
How to mock a static final class which has defined some other static final class?

Problem Description:
When I want to write some unit test case for a final class ApplianceRelationshipUtils.java, and in this final class ApplianceRelationshipUtils.java, always invork another static class ApplianceUtilities.java. So I need to use powermock to mock the static class ApplianceUtilities.java like this:

```
    // mock the class for one method only
    PowerMock.mockStaticPartialNice(ApplianceUtilities.class,"getApplianceVersion");
```

But in the ApplianceUtilities.java defined many static final classs like these:

```
private static final IMesUtils m_mesUtils = new MesUtils();
private static final IEndpointUtilities m_endpointUtils = new DefaultEndpointUtilities(m_mesUtils);
private static final ICasUtilities m_casUtils = new  DefaultCasUtilities(m_endpointUtils);
private static final IHAApplianceUtilities m_haUtils = new HAApplianceUtils(m_endpointUtils, m_casUtils);
```

So when I run the testcase there will throw out some exception as below:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.ibm.usmi.services.updates.util.RestartUtilities.<init>(Lcom/ibm/usmi/services/updates/util/IRcsUtilities;Lcom/ibm/usmi/services/updates/util/MesUtils;Lcom/ibm/usmi/services/updates/util/IUpdateUtils;)V
at com.ibm.vmi.updates.appliance.util.HAApplianceUtils.<init>(HAApplianceUtils.java:222)
at com.ibm.vmi.updates.appliance.util.ApplianceUtilities.<clinit>(ApplianceUtilities.java:89)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.setCallbacksHelper(Enhancer.java:616)
at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.setThreadCallbacks(Enhancer.java:609)
at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.registerCallbacks(Enhancer.java:578)
at org.easymock.internal.ClassProxyFactory.createProxy(ClassProxyFactory.java:194)
at org.easymock.internal.MocksControl.createMock(MocksControl.java:60)
at org.easymock.internal.MocksControl.createMock(MocksControl.java:98)
at org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.doCreateMock(PowerMock.java:2214)
at org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.doMock(PowerMock.java:2163)
at org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.createMock(PowerMock.java:76)
at org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.createPartialMock(PowerMock.java:762)
at com.ibm.vmi.updates.appliance.relationship.ApplianceRelationshipUtilsTest.test_validateApplianceReqs(ApplianceRelationshipUtilsTest.java:77)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:66)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:312)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:86)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:94)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:296)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:112)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:73)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:284)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:84)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:209)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:148)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:122)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:102)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: Which bundle of PowerMock are you using? As referenced by this page: http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/GettingStarted

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm those errors are coming from the versions mismatch between Mockito and PowerMock. We should define the dependency versions only in the parent `pom.xml` file and reference them in the child module `pom.xml` files.

I provide an example here. The child `pom.xml` file provided,

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
  <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
  <version>${mockito.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
  <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
  <version>${powermock.version}</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
  <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
  <version>${powermock.version}</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

In the parent `pom.xml` file provided.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

   ...........................................................

  <properties>
    <powermock.version>1.7.4</powermock.version>
    <powermock-api.version>2.0.2</powermock-api.version>
    <mockito.version>2.8.9</mockito.version>
  </properties>

  .............................

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a compatibility issue between Mockito and PowerMock so I leave here the solution that worked for me in case someone else runs into the same error:

> **JUnit**
>
> JUnit 4.4 or above Add the following to your pom.xml if you're
>   using JUnit 4.4 or above:
>
> ```
>    <properties>
>      <powermock.version>1.7.1</powermock.version> 
>    </properties>
>    <dependencies>
>     <dependency>
>      <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
>      <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
>      <version>${powermock.version}</version>
>      <scope>test</scope>    
>     </dependency>    
>     <dependency>
>     <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
>     <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
>     <version>${powermock.version}</version>
>     <scope>test</scope>    
>    </dependency>
> ```
>
> JUnit 4.0-4.3 Add the following to your pom.xml if you're using JUnit
>   4.0-4.3:
>
> ```
> <properties>
>      <powermock.version>1.7.1</powermock.version> 
> </properties> 
> <dependencies>    
>  <dependency>
>        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
>        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4-legacy</artifactId>
>        <version>${powermock.version}</version>
>        <scope>test</scope>    </dependency>    <dependency>
>        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
>        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
>       <version>${powermock.version}</version>
>        <scope>test</scope>   
>  </dependency> 
> </dependencies>
> ```

Official documentation for PowerMock when using Mockito and Maven: https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito-Maven

Answer (score -1):

You can give @SuppressStaticInitializationFor a try and see if that helps.
https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/SuppressUnwantedBehavior

Comment: This is a perfect example of why links are bad. PowerMock moved to GitHub and now this link does not work. While this will be hypocritical here is the new link: https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/SuppressUnwantedBehavior